# No logining slash command in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I need to create to slash command, using library discord.py, but I can't do this: slash command has no loginning, but no one errors.

Code:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import os

token = 'ТОКЕН'
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '*', intents = discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.tree.sync()

class MyModal(discord.ui.Modal, title = 'Title'):
    Test_one = discord.ui.TextInput(label = 'label', placeholder = 'placeholder', required = False, max_length = 100, min_length = 5, style = discord.TextStyle.short)

@client.tree.command(name = 'слеш-команда', description = 'Описание')
async def command(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_modal(MyModal())

client.run(token)
```

Thanks!

I full checking all code.

Answer (score -1):

I think you forgot to **import discord** itself. This worked for me:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import os

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '*', intents = discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.tree.sync()

class MyModal(discord.ui.Modal, title = 'Title'):
    Test_one = discord.ui.TextInput(label = 'label', placeholder = 'placeholder', required = False, max_length = 100, min_length = 5, style = discord.TextStyle.short)

@client.tree.command(name = 'слеш-команда', description = 'Описание')
async def command(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_modal(MyModal())

client.run('ENTER_YOUR_TOKEN_HERE')
```

Comment: I imported discord, but this no copied

Comment: Still doesn't work